SharePoint page element that shows posts on related general channel as a newsfeed
I have a Teams channel and a related SharePoint site. I would like the home page of the site to have a page element which shows say the last 3 posts from the general channel in a news feed style.
I can see that I can add an element (web part) to pull in news eg an external RSS feed but is there a way to pull in news generated as posts in the channel. Do I create an RSS feed from the channel and then use the RSS web part ? Or is there a more direct way to do this ?
NOTE: I cannot add the RSS app for security reasons


You can use Power Automate to fetch Teams channel messages and sync them to a SharePoint list. Once the data is in the list, use the List Web Part to display the latest entries. Configure the view to show only the most recent three posts.

Custom but not much custom solution  (less complex than you may think!)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tabs-in-sharepoint


